# css-loader@2.11 shows error message: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css-loader/locals'

Tags: webpack, css-loader

As I was integrating `css-loader@2.11`, the following error appeared:

[image: css-loader/locals not found]

However, when I downgrade to `css-loader@0.28.10` it all worked. I tried to trace the code in `css-loader` myself, I still couldn't find the problem.

Although I doubt it's the problem of `css-loader` since it seems to execute with no problem (It execute through the debug logs I put in the code).

The following is my webpack setup for `.css` rule:

**base.webpack.config.js**

```
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: true, // enable css module
                importLoaders: 2 ,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                exportOnlyLocals: true,
              },
            },
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "postcss-flexibility": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-smart-import": "^0.7.6",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "universal-webpack": "^0.6.11",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
```

Please give me a direction to resolve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: did you try to remove the `exportOnlyLocals` option ? The doc says it is not intended to be used with style-loader (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#exportonlylocals)

Comment: I think it work when you downgrade because this option was added in css-loader@2

Comment: sorry I did not intend to put `exportOnlyLocals` on the question above. the webpack config in my project does not contain `exportOnlyLocals`. Still couldn't get it going with `css-loader@2.11`

Comment: that option was just me fiddling `css-loader` and try to observe the code